# Call Function From UserControl on ASPX From UserControl on MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have MainLayout.master that has UC_Menu.ascx on it.

I have a page named Customer.aspx that uses MainLayout.master. Customer.aspx also contains a UserControl named UC_Details.ascx.

How can I have UC_Menu.ascx call a function that is in UC_Details.ascx with this scenario?

I've seen a few similar examples, but none that match this type of layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should raise event from UC_Menu.ascx, then handle it in Master page and raise event again from Master page already. Finally you can intercept event with event handler in Customer.aspx and call function from UC_Details.ascx.

So, the code for this issue should be:

1) Inside your UC_Menu.ascx.vb raise an event:

```
Partial Class UserControls_UC_Menu
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event SomethingChanged As EventHandler

    Public Sub SomethingHappend()
        RaiseEvent SomethingChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

End Class
```

2) In Master page catch event and raise it to Customer.aspx

```
Public Event SomethingChanged As EventHandler

Private Sub UC_MenuInstance_SomethingChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UC_Menu.SomethingChanged
     RaiseEvent Me.SomethingChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

3) Define in Customer.aspx markup after page directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/MainLayout.master" %>
```

4) Inside UC_Details.ascx.vb define some method that should be called:

```
Public Sub DoWork()
   'Do some work here
End Sub
```

5) Place into Customer.aspx.vb:

```
' Add handler for Master page event
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    AddHandler Me.Master.SomethingChanged, AddressOf MasterEventHandler
End Sub

' Call UC_Details user control function here
Private Sub MasterEventHandler(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        UC_DetailsInstance.DoWork()
    End Sub
```

Comment: As I understand, UC_Menu.ascx belong to Master page. It is a good practice to communicate from child to parent control throw event. So, you should raise event in UC_Menu.ascx and handle it in Master page code. Then we should undertsand that Master page doesn't know anything about it content page. So, the only possible way to communicate from Master page to content page is again raising event from Master page. Then you should set in Customer.aspx event handler for this event and inside event handler you should call required function on UC_Details.ascx, which is child of  Customer.aspx page.

Comment: I'm new to using RaiseEvent, so I've been trying to read up on it.  Can you explain how you would setup the code in Master to do something simple like change the text of a label on the master page?

Comment: Which language you prefer vb.net or c#?

Comment: I'm having problems with setp #5 when working with Customer.aspx.vb.

Comment: I've got almost everything completed from the code provided, however I am not able to get intelisense to display DoWork when trying to type  UC_DetailsInstance.DoWork().

Comment: Ok. I fixed my problem. I was able to get everything to work correctly. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this. Working with RaiseEvent makes much more sense to me now.

Comment: Don't worry. It is a temporary state. Just build web site and then close and open Customer.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1):

Interesting scenario.  Have the page implement an interface:

```
public interface IDetailsPage
{
   UC_Details DetailsControl { get; }
}
```

The page would then directly expose the control of the property.  In UC_Menu, use:

```
if (this.Page is IDetailsPage)
    ((IDetailsPage)this.Page).DetailsControl.CallMethod();
```

HTH.

Comment: I had the UC_Detail page implement an interface, but when I try to expose the control property in UC_Menu, I receive an error saying that IDetailsPage is not defined.

Comment: Just realized that i did not reference UC_Details in the source code for UC_Menu.

Comment: I am now able to expose my function in the codebehind for UC_Menu.ascx but it is never executed because "if (this.Page is IDetailsPage)" is never true. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You should find UC_Menu on master page, and call it's method:

```
var c = (UC_Menu) Master.FindControl("UC_Menu");
if (c != null)
{
    c.CallMethod();
}
```

Checkout [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) article.

Comment: UC_Details is in the user control, not in the master. you got it backwards

Comment: @Victor change UC_Details to UC_Menu. Doesn't matter. It's the way you can acces control on MasterPage.